# Error in showing my modal in React component

Tags: javascript, reactjs, modal-dialog, frontend, jsx

I'm building an app with React and I'm trying to implement a modal appearing after error occurring.

This is a simply login card with input boxes and I do a post request to login or sign-up new users.
If there's any error in my form or users already exists I want to popup a modal with error messages like the following.

I can't understand why it isn't showing. The error is ok and the backdrop is visible. Any help is appreciated.
There's my code:

This is the JSX code:

```
import { useHttpClient } from '../hooks/http-hook';
const { isLoading, error, sendRequest, clearError } = useHttpClient();

...

    return (
                <React.Fragment>
                    <ErrorModal error={error} onClear={clearError} />
                    <div className="container">
                        {isLoading && <LoadingSpinner asOverlay />}
                        <div className="card card-container">
                            <img id="profile-img" className="profile-img-card" alt="Login Avatar" src={require("../../assets/images/avatar.png")} />
                            <p id="profile-name" className="profile-name-card"></p>
                            <form className="form-signin" onSubmit={loginSubmitHandler}>
                                <span id="reauth-email" className="reauth-email"></span>
                                {!isLoginMode && (
                                    <Input
                                        element="input"
                                        id="username"
                                        type="text"
                                        title="Username"
                                        placeholder="USERNAME"
                                        validators={[VALIDATOR_REQUIRE()]}
                                        errorText="Required."
                                        onInput={inputHandler}
                                    />
                                )}
                                <Input
                                    element="input"
                                    id="email"
                                    type="text"
                                    title="EMAIL"
                                    placeholder="EMAIL"
                                    validators={[VALIDATOR_EMAIL()]}
                                    errorText="Invalid email address."
                                    onInput={inputHandler}
                                />
                                <Input
                                    element="input"
                                    id="password"
                                    type="password"
                                    title="PASSWORD"
                                    placeholder="PASSWORD"
                                    validators={[VALIDATOR_MINLENGTH(5)]}
                                    errorText="Your password must have at least 5 characters."
                                    onInput={inputHandler}
                                />
                                <Button type="submit" disabled={!formState.isValid}>
                                    {isLoginMode ? 'LOGIN' : 'SIGNUP'}
                                </Button>
                            </form>
                            <Button inverse onClick={switchModeHandler}>
                                SWITCH TO {isLoginMode ? 'SIGNUP' : 'LOGIN'}
                            </Button>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </React.Fragment>
            )
```

This is my Modal.js

```
import React from 'react';
import ReactDOM from 'react-dom';
import { CSSTransition } from 'react-transition-group';

import Backdrop from './Backdrop';
import './Modal.css';

const ModalOverlay = props => {
  const content = (
    <div className={`modal ${props.className}`} style={props.style}>
      <header className={`modal__header ${props.headerClass}`}>
        <h2>{props.header}</h2>
      </header>
      <form
        onSubmit={
          props.onSubmit ? props.onSubmit : event => event.preventDefault()
        }
      >
        <div className={`modal__content ${props.contentClass}`}>
          {props.children}
        </div>
        <footer className={`modal__footer ${props.footerClass}`}>
          {props.footer}
        </footer>
      </form>
    </div>
  );
  return ReactDOM.createPortal(content, document.getElementById('modal-hook'));
};

const Modal = props => {
  return (
    <React.Fragment>
      {props.show && <Backdrop onClick={props.onCancel} />}
      <CSSTransition
        in={props.show}
        mountOnEnter
        unmountOnExit
        timeout={200}
        classNames="modal"
      >
        <ModalOverlay {...props} />
      </CSSTransition>
    </React.Fragment>
  );
};

export default Modal;
```

And this my ErrorModal.js

```
import React from 'react';

import Modal from './Modal';
import Button from '../formElements/Button';

const ErrorModal = props => {
  return (
    <Modal
      onCancel={props.onClear}
      header="An Error Occurred!"
      show={!!props.error}
      footer={<Button onClick={props.onClear}>Okay</Button>}
    >
      <p>{props.error}</p>
    </Modal>
  );
};

export default ErrorModal;
```

Comment: I would suggest using this. It's a very well built popup for react https://www.npmjs.com/package/reactjs-popup

Comment: so when is `error` set? and  you are using it as both boolean for `show` property and as error text?

Comment: @Apostolos I use an http hook to manage my requests and it returns `{ isLoading, error, sendRequest, clearError } `

Comment: It seems my CSSTransition is not working properly... The backdrop and the errors are fine, it's just the component visualization and can't find the problem

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It was simply my bootstrap.css to create a mess.....

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="%PUBLIC_URL%/stylesheets/bootstrap/bootstrap.css">
```

I simply renamed the modal class in custom_modal